# can a child activity respond to orientation changes while parent activity remains constant?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

Is it possible in Android for an Activity, called from an Activity whose orientation is fixed, to respond to orientation changes?

i.e. AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_Parent"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity_Child"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent"
        android:label="@string/app_name />
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Activity_Parent.java

```
public class Activity_Parent extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle sIS){
        super.onCreate(sIS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);

        Intent activityChild = new Intent(this, Activity_Child.class);
        startActivity(activityChild);
    }
}
```

Activity_Child.java

```
public class Activity_Child extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle sIS){
        super.onCreate(sIS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child); 
    }
}
```

With the above activities, the child activity acts as though its orientation has been set to landscape. How would have the parent activities static orientation not effect the child activity's orientation?

Comment: I think there is something missing in your question. An activity started with `startActivity` isn't considered a child activity, and unless you're doing something else, the 'parent' activity won't be visible whilst the child activity is on screen - are you doing something like applying a dialog theme, or setting a transparent window background? Are you doing something with multiple windows or samsungs multitasking apis?

Comment: transparent window background on Activity_Child

Answer (score -1):

add this child activity xml in manifest

```
 <activity
    android:name=".Activity_Parent"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:name=".Activity_Child"
    android:label="@string/app_name />
```

Comment: This causes both activities to be set to portrait

Comment: the exact same; both activities are stuck in portrait orientation

Comment: android:screenOrientation is it there in your manifest anywhere else

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); is it there in your code

Comment: nope; the programmatic code is what you see there. Each layout has a centered TextView that simply says either "Parent" or "Child"

Comment: not sure what you are doing but this should work also what is child fragment dont see any fragment in your code

Comment: that was a typo. sorry. it has been fixed

Comment: check your themes then